# Is there an optimal python function to search for every element in a certain list and see if it exists in a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I wants to search for every element in a certain list and see if it exists in a column in a dataframe `spotify_data` the `spotify_data['Genre']` is a series

This is my code:

```py
genre_names = take(1545, all_genres) # a function that extracts certain # of indices from dictionary
streams_on_genre = []
for genre in genre_names:
    streams = 0
    for index, row in spotify_data.iterrows():
        if genre in row['Genre']:
            streams += row['Streams']
    streams_on_genre.append(streams)
```

Comment: please add `df.head()` to post

Comment: Is `spotify_data` a dataframe? If so: `sum(spotify_data['Genre'].isin(genre_names))` should do the trick I believe. Best bet when approaching things like this with dataframes is: Don't loop. Only once you've exhausted all options would a loop be necessary, and that is rare.

Comment: which library are you using? `pandas`?

Comment: Do you mean .isin?

Comment: Please add sample data from `spotify_data` to your question. For example, we don't know if `row['Genre']` is a string or a list, and that makes a big difference to the code you need.

Comment: @MoRe Okay I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to search every element in the array. **the dataframe does even better than this**.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c':['apple','orange','banana']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(5 in df['b'].values)          # prints True
print('pear' in df['c'].values)     # prints false
```

- checks if `5` is in column b. since it is, it returns `True`.
- checks if `pear` is in column c. since it is **not**, it returns `False`.

You can do this with all the data types.

Answer (score 0):

For the substring match that you are doing (Not faster than 2 for loops)

```py
genre_names = set(take(1545, all_genres)) # a function that extracts certain # of indices from dictionary
streams_on_genre = {genre: spotify_data["Streams"][spotify_data['Genre'].apply(lambda x: genre in x)] for genre in genre_names}
```

For an exact match (Should be faster)

```py
genre_names = set(take(1545, all_genres)) # a function that extracts certain # of indices from dictionary
streams_on_genre = {genre: spotify_data["Streams"][spotify_data['Genre'] == genre] for genre in genre_names}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to count the number of times the genres you are interested are in the column. A pure pandas approach might look like:

```
spotify_data['Genre'].value_counts().reindex(genre_names).fillna(0)
```

This will give you a series with the counts as the values and the index will be the genres.

Alternatively, you could get a dictionary of counts if you want, using vanilla python:

```
from collections import Counter
genre_counts = Counter(spotify_data['Genre'])
```

Then, if you only want the specific counts, you can filter it back down:

```
# as another dict
result_dict = {k:genre_counts[k] for k in genre_names}
# as a list
result_list = [genre_counts[k] for k in genre_names]
```

Both of these approaches will be performant. However note, both of these approaches only check for **exact matches**